# multi-dimensional array hierarchy

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, hierarchy

I like to know how can I get the hierarchy by the identifier.

This is an example :

```
$inputArray = array(
        array(
            "text" => "Dir1",
            "parent_id" => "",
            "id" => "1",
            "filesize" => "109"
    ),array(
        "text" => "dir2",
        "parent_id" => "",
        "id" => "2",
        "filesize" => "88",
        "children" => array(
                "text" => "Dir3",
                "parent_id" => "2",
                "id" => "3",
                "filesize" => "",
                "children" => array(
                    "text" => "dir4",
                    "parent_id" => "3",
                    "id" => "4",
                    "filesize" => "",
                    "children" => array(
                        "text" => "dir5",
                        "parent_id" => "4",
                        "id" => "4",
                        "filesize" => ""
                    )
                )
        )
    ));
```

looking for this example :

```
dir3/dir4/dir5
```

Comment: Do you want such output base on `children` arrays?

Comment: yes yes exactly

Comment: for example get_tree(5);  // i get dir3/dir4/dir5

Comment: https://eval.in/921117

Answer (score 0):

```
function getText($array) {
  $save[]  = $array['text'];
  if (isset($array['children'])) {
     $save = array_merge($save, getText($array['children']));
  }
  return $save;  
}

foreach($inputArray as $x) {
     echo implode('/', getText($x)) . "\n";
}
```

result

```
Dir1
dir2/Dir3/dir4/dir5
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/921117)

Comment: yes correct thank you so much, just i want to ask you. how can i put Dir1 as an element in a new array, and dir2/Dir3/dir4/dir5
for example `$new_array = array('Dir1','dir2/Dir3/dir4/dir5');`

Comment: Replace echo with $new[] =

Comment: its possible to change the algorithm and look by the id, by passing the element id in the function as a parameter? :)

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: `function getText($array) {
   $save[]  = $array['text'];
   if (if_array("id", array_keys($array))) {
      $save = array_merge($save, $this->getText($array['children']));
   }
   return $save;
 }`